# I hope to find an open source solution for Mosaic datasets

Tags: gis

A project needs to manage massive image data (like satellite images), and publish it as a service for use on the web side, and control the display of some part of the image on the web side. Tessellation data sets can solve this requirement. Is there any similar open source solution to solve this problem? Or I need to go to a community where I can get help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Look at [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) it supports [image mosaics](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/index.html) and [image pyramids](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagepyramid.html) to store and serve image data using OGC standards such as [WMS](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/index.html) and [WCS](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wcs/index.html). You may find [gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions) a good place to ask further questions.

> GeoServer is a OGC compliant implementation of a number of open standards such as Web Feature Service (WFS), Web Map Service (WMS), and Web Coverage Service (WCS).
>
> Additional formats and publication options are available including Web Map Tile Service (WMTS) and extensions for Catalogue Service (CSW) and Web Processing Service (WPS).